# Cómo inicio de manera normal con npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

Todo funcionaba bien hasta que decidí instalar bootstrap con los siguientes comandos:

```
npm i --save bootstrap @popperjs/core
npm i --save-dev sass
```

Y ahora cuando ejecuto npm run dev, no funciona y aparece:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\elver\OneDrive\Documents\WEB\-- Ejercices JavaScript\1.1 Practice\proyectoconVite\react-task-application\node_modules\.vite\deps'
```

He intentado limpiando cache, reinstalando node, desinstalando bootstrap, pero no funciona.

Ojalá encuentre una respuesta, estoy empezando con esto de la programación web.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, sugiero verificar que estas en el directorio raiz del proyecto, tambien se puede reiniciar otro proyecto e ir instalando los mismos paquetes en secuencia para saber si puedes emular el problema y encontrar en donde se daño la configuración.